# Counting characters in android

Tags: java, android, string, count, words

I need to count words. Starts from the character " > " to " : "

for example: I have this line: **> User says: Hi people**

I wonder how I can count the total of selection which start in ">" and finish ":"

Actually, my code in Java are:

```
String groupMessage = new String("> User says : Hi people");
String search = new String(">");


TextView groupMessageBox = (TextView) this
        .findViewById(R.id.groupMessageBox);

Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(groupMessage);

int length = search.length();
String input = WordtoSpan.toString();
int startIndex = input.indexOf(search);
while(startIndex > length)
{
    WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(140, 117, 189)), startIndex, startIndex + length,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    WordtoSpan.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startIndex, startIndex + length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    startIndex = input.indexOf(search, startIndex + length);
}
groupMessageBox.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Someone can help me? Greetings

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I'm sorry, I wanted to say ":"

Comment: Are you wanting to count words or characters? I based my answer on your title (characters), but now I notice the contents relates to counting words.

Comment: Side note: make sure your Java variables are `camelCase`. So `WordToSpan` should be `wordToSpan`, otherwise we'll assume it's a class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int start = groupMessage.indexOf(">") + 1;
int end = groupMessage.indexOf(":") - 1;
int numWords = groupMessage.substring(start, end).split("\\s+").length;
```

This code assumes that you only care about the first time ">" and ":" come up, and that there is always a space after the ">" and before the ":"

Comment: This assumes you want to count words, which is what your first sentence says. However I just noticed the title is about characters.

Comment: Should be `substring` (lowercase), plus you're missing a closing `;`.

Comment: @Duncan thanks, this is what you get when you rely on your IDE too much!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
int length = groupMessage.indexOf(":") - groupMessage.indexOf(">") - 1;
```

It counts every character (including spaces) between the `>` and the `:`.